# Closing main window doesn't stop tkinter app process

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, matplotlib-widget

I try to implement matplotlib chart into tkinter app and it works but after closing main window (`m`) the process is still going and cant stop it without closing the console. Why?

```py
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import tkinter as tk
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


def plot_canvas(master):
    points = [(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 25), (20, 25), (25, 0)]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
    fig.add_subplot(111).plot([x[0] for x in points],
                              [x[1] for x in points],
                              marker='.',
                              linestyle='-')

    # ax.
    # ax.plot([10, 20], [25, 25], marker='.', linestyle=':', color='green')
    return tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=master).get_tk_widget()


m = tk.Tk()
wgt = plot_canvas(m)
wgt.grid()
m.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. change `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` to `matplotlib.use('Agg')`
2. use `matplotlib.figure.Figure(...)` instead of `plt.figure(...)`